# Adding value to ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, domains

I am having problems with ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Online.

I am working in an already existing database and I am creating polygons to symbolise areas in which types of animals have been seen.

I am missing a value (a fish sort) but I cannot figure out how to add a value. When I do it in ArcGIS Pro it will not register in ArcGIS Online.

Should it be done via ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Pro?

[image]

I need to add Arctic Char as a type But I am unsure of whether that should be done via ArcGis Online or ArcGIS Pro. My logic says that it should be doable through ArcGIS Pro. I have tried to add value in attribute table, without any luck, I have also tried out designs, without any luck.

[image]

Comment: Likely a relevant questions: Where is this dataset you are trying to adjust the drop-down for stored (is it a local feature class, a feature class you've published to a local server, a feature service hosted on ArcGIS Online, etc...?)  And second, is that drop down a subtype or a domain (those are the only 2 options I know of for a drop-down like that)?

Comment: I'm working from an already existing project, but from what I'm aware of, it should be stored as a feature hosted on ArcGIS Online.

Comment: John, in terms of drop down type, I'm not sure which ones they are. I'm aware of the two types, but I'm not entirely sure how they play a role in term sof creating new types.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to consider adding domains or subtypes via the Design dialogue. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/view-and-edit-fields-domains-and-subtypes.htm

If you want to be more flexible and add the ability to enter free text, have another blank text subtype per the post here: https://community.esri.com/thread/166486